# How to use a list as parameter in clause WHERE in python and CosmoDB

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

i got a list of ids and i want to use this list as parameter like this:

```
list_id = ['4833', '43443', '431431']
qry = f"""SELECT
            c.nm_cnae as Nome_CNAE
            FROM cnae as c
            WHERE c.cod_cnae = '{list_id}'"""
resultado_busca = cosmosengine.query('cnae', qry)
resultado_busca = list(resultado_busca)
```

how should i do this works?

I'm using azure cosmosdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to find all the ones that have an id in the list it would be:

```
list_id = ['4833', '43443', '431431']
qry = f"""SELECT
            c.nm_cnae as Nome_CNAE
            FROM cnae as c
            WHERE c.cod_cnae IN ({','.join(list_id)})"""
resultado_busca = cosmosengine.query('cnae', qry)
resultado_busca = list(resultado_busca)
```

This uses the IN operator in sql: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

`','.join(list_id)` creates a string where each value is separated by a comma.